# Split an array in two parts such that the difference of their sums is minimum

Tags: arrays, difference, sub-array

Ok let's say that I have an array as `1 4 2 3 1` and I want to split it in 2 sub arrays such that the absolute difference of their sums is minimum.

That is to say as for the above example the 2 sub-arrays would be `4 2` and `3 1 1` which is `|6 - 5|` that is 1.

It seems to be a dynamic programming question but I'd like to solve it the conventional way.

I am not looking for exact answers but rather the ideology about how should I approach this problem.
Any hints would be appreciated. But just the hints as I'd like to solve it on my own thereafter.

We are not concerned about the order of the elements and their can be duplicate elements as well.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't contain any code

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to find the minimum by any means then the brute force way would be to find all the ways to split the array in two and find the difference of sum of the numbers in each pair. Then store the minimum (and the two sub arrays) or a list of the minimums and replace this if the program finds a new minimum. Iterate over all the possible pairs and there you go your new subarray.

Depending on how you code this there are way to improve on this method. For example if you have the pair `[1,2,3] and [4,5]` you don't need to also do `[4,5] and [1,2,3]` as this would be the same pair of subarrays.

I don't want to write an actual way of doing this as you did specify you want to try it yourself